# Bash: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script that needs to know the processor architecture. I'm doing this way:

```
if [["$(uname -m)" = "x86_64"]]; then
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
else
echo "Nossa! Você só pode usar 3,5GB de memória RAM. Que triste :( Vou baixar a versão 32bits pra você tá?"
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.rpm
fi
```

But when I execute the code, I receive:

```
instala_chrome.sh: line 35: [[x86_64: command not found
```

Anyone can help me to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use:

```
if [[ "$(uname -m)" == "x86_64" ]]; then
```

Notice the space between `[[` and first parameter, two `=` signs , and the space between `"x86_64"` and `]]`

Also, it is not a good idea to include `!` inside echo :)

I think that that's the best place to refer to when doing such operations: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: This works. Thank you. Can you recommend a online documentation for reading?

Comment: Please see my edited answer. If you think that this works and it solved your problem (and only then), then please mark my answer as the accepted one as well.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you need a space after the `[[` and a space before the `]]` and the `]];` should be all together.  Also, it is considered good practice to put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of the script so that execution knows which shell to use.